# How to select items from drop down menu using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have been trying to automate a search using Selenium. I simply want to search terms (say `Pink Floyd`) but the file type should be pdf. Here is what I have done so far:

```
    //Query term
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("as_q"));
    String finalQuery = "pink floyd";
    element.sendKeys(finalQuery);

    //File type selection
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("as_filetype_button"));
    elem.sendKeys("Adobe Acrobat pdf (.pdf)");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/form/div[5]/div[9]/div[2]/input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

This puts the term in the appropriate place and the drop down for file types are expanded but pdf option is not selected. Any help?

I am using Selenium 2.53.0.

**EDIT**

The following code segment perfectly worked as per the accepted answer for this question. However, all on a sudden the code segment is not working. I am a bit surprised to find this out. Previously, I was able to select PDF automatically with the following code segment but now, nothing gets selected.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("as_q"));
 String finalQuery = "pink floyd";
 element.sendKeys(finalQuery);
 driver.findElement(By.id("as_filetype_button")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class=class-name][@value='pdf']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i do it, find the `li` that matches the `class='goog-menuitem'` and `value='pdf'`, i inspected the element. You can go directly with `value='pdf'` but just to make sure we are looking at the file type dropdown we added the class.

```
        driver.findElement(By.id("as_filetype_button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='goog-menuitem'][@value='pdf']")).click();
```

You can still declare it with `WebElement`, i just prefer it shorthand. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. How did you find the class goog-menuitem and the values? I really need to understand this because perhaps at some point, I might have to select values from other drop drowns on this page.

Comment: F12 inspect element, click the dropdown go to the bottom of the html source, you will see there the different menus for each of their dropdowns, this is a common approach on custom javascript dropdowns. If my answer helped you please accept this as answer, will appreciate it very much! thanks

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: Interestingly, the solution is not working all on a sudden. What can be the reason? The dropdown choices are not getting selected anymore. However, it worked perfectly before as per this suggestion.